# Show navbar brand only after scrolling certain height

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to keep the navbar brand hidden at first when the page loads and only make it appear after scrolling down a certain height.

Have tried below code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('#logo')[0].style.display = 'hidden';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('#logo')[0].style.display = 'visible';
  }
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `getElementsByClassName`, and give it an ID

Everything starting with `#` (hash) is an ID, Everything starting with an `.` (dot) is a class name. Also, `getElementById` does not return an array, so you don't need to pick the first element (with `[0]`).

Try something like:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'hidden';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'visible';
  }
});
```

Though, as you are using jQuery, you could also clean it up more and use something like:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    $('#logo').style.display = 'hidden';
  } else {
    $('#logo').style.display = 'visible';
  }
});
```

or as Reza suggested use:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    $('#logo').hide();
  } else {
    $('#logo').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also one more thing. It is flashing the logo during page reload. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It is hard to tell, though could be related to the fact that your browser on a reload scrolls to the position where you were. In case that is the case, hide it per default (CSS) and add an onload to show it. On the other hand, if that is the case, I normally don't bother to much about it, as normal users don't reload that much ;)

Comment: is there is a `hidden` value for display, from what I know to hide an element you have to write `none`.  am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this

```js
let scrollerBlock = $(".logo");


$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    scrollerBlock.fadeIn(400);
  } else {
    scrollerBlock.fadeOut(400);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #777;
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  display: none;
  width: 210px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27") no-repeat;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="block">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

if you need smoothness

Answer (score 0):

Here The Code, I also added a beta absolute line to help you visualize what happens

if the red line is not visible then the logo disappear

I also change the display from `hidden` to `none` because in css there isn't `hidden` for the `display` property

try to Run the Snippet below to see the result
(make sure then to delete the beta line, following the comments I write for you)

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY > 1000) {
    document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('betaLine').textContent = "1000px THE LOGO IS HIDDEN!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'grid';

    /* delete this below, is only for seeing where is 1000 */
    document.getElementById('betaLine').textContent = Math.round(window.scrollY) + "px";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center start;
  padding-left: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

main div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

#betaLine {
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 100vw;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="logo">
      CompanyLogo.
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div>1 section, scroll to the next</div>
    <div>2 section, scroll to the next</div>
    <div>3 section, scroll to the next</div>
    <div>4 section, the last</div>
  </main>

  <!-- delete this below, is only for seeing where is 1000 -->
  <div id="betaLine">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```